# How can i remove empty object in an array in Azure Logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I just want to remove the empty object in an array before sending it to another HTTP request

```
  "documentId": "87f1bf4b-190a-40dd-b155-89b7530160ad",
  "tags": [
    {
      "Title": "Expiration Date",
      "AKA": "",
      "Value": "September 25, 1980",
      "Content": "Expired September 25, 1980",
      "path": "//Document/Sect/P",
      "page": 0
    },
    [],
    {
      "Title": "Expiration Date",
      "AKA": "",
      "Value": "September 25, 1980",
      "Content": "Expired September 25, 1980",
      "path": "//Document/Sect/P",
      "page": 0
    },
    {
      "Title": "Expiration Date",
      "AKA": "",
      "Value": "September 25, 1980",
      "Content": "Expired September 25, 1980",
      "path": "//Document/Sect/P",
      "page": 0
    },
    {
      "Title": "Expiration Date",
      "AKA": "",
      "Value": "September 25, 1980",
      "Content": "Expired September 25, 1980",
      "path": "//Document/Sect/P",
      "page": 0
    },
    {
      "Title": "Expiration Date",
      "AKA": "",
      "Value": "September 25, 1980",
      "Content": "Expired September 25, 1980",
      "path": "//Document/Sect/P",
      "page": 0
    },
    {
      "Title": "Expiration Date",
      "AKA": "",
      "Value": "September 25, 1980",
      "Content": "Expired September 25, 1980",
      "path": "//Document/Sect/P",
      "page": 0
    },
    {
      "Title": "Expiration Date",
      "AKA": "",
      "Value": "September 25, 1980",
      "Content": "Expired September 25, 1980",
      "path": "//Document/Sect/P",
      "page": 0
    },
    {
      "Title": "Expiration Date",
      "AKA": "",
      "Value": "September 25, 1980",
      "Content": "Expired September 25, 1980",
      "path": "//Document/Sect/P",
      "page": 0
    },
    {
      "Title": "Expiration Date",
      "AKA": "",
      "Value": "September 25, 1980",
      "Content": "Expired September 25, 1980",
      "path": "//Document/Sect/P",
      "page": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I just want to remove '[]' in the array.

Here's how i compose the json

```
{
  "documentId": @{triggerBody()?['Name']},
  "tags": [
    @{if(equals(length(json(body('HTTP').results)),0), null,json(body('HTTP').results)[0])},
    @{if(equals(length(json(body('HTTP_2').results)),0), json(body('HTTP_2').results),json(body('HTTP_2').results)[0])},
    @{json(body('HTTP_3').results)[0]},
    @{json(body('HTTP_4').results)[0]},
    @{json(body('HTTP_5').results)[0]},
    @{json(body('HTTP_6').results)[0]},
    @{json(body('HTTP_7').results)[0]},
    @{json(body('Method_2').results)[0]},
    @{json(body('Method_3').results)[0]},
    @{json(body('Method_4').results)[0]}
  ]
}
```

As you can see, objects came from different HTTP request. are there any other way to construct the json without adding the null or [] object response from another HTTP request?

Comment: Can you provide the original JSON so we can replicate your flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the sample that you have provided, One way to achieve this that you can directly use `Replace()` function to remove "[]" from your response. Below is the expression I used.

```
replace(outputs('Compose'),'[],','')
```

[image]

Comment: hi, i'm having this error when i added that compose 2

Failed to save logic app samworkflow. The template validation failed: 'The action(s) 'HTTP, HTTP_2, HTTP_3, HTTP_4, HTTP_5, HTTP_6, HTTP_7, Method_2, Method_3, Method_4' referenced by 'inputs' in action 'Compose' are not defined in the template.'.

Comment: @edoms06, I have directly added the HTTP request that you have provided in Compose action. https://i.imgur.com/51ST4xB.png which gave me an output of https://i.imgur.com/AO6PxOG.png

Comment: yup, sorry I changed the http request method name. but I have another error.

https://imgur.com/a/vZr2vvK

InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose_2' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'replace' expects its first parameter 'string' to be a string. The provided value is of type 'Object'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#replace for usage details.'.

Comment: so you use a string and not object which you can use in replace method.
what I did is convert the object to string and replace the [], then convert back to json

Comment: Yes, as replace is a string function, you need to read it the complete request as a string, replace "[]" and then convert it back to json using `json(<Output from the previous step>)`.